# Include Jira story number in apk name

Tags: android, jenkins, jira

Thanks for your help in advance. I am using Android Studio, Linux-RHEL 7, Jenkins, Bitbucket and Jira for my project. I was thinking is there any way where we could set the apk name that is generated from jenkins which consists of jira story number in it. I see that we could setup Jenkins build number to be shown in the apk name. But is there a way we use jira number in apk name or use jira number in the jenkins build number.